# using source code directly in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: directory

I have a ton of cpp, h and other files arranged in folders and lots of nesting as well. How can I use it directly from Visual Studio? 
Because I don't have the .sln files and I don't know the dependency tree.

How can I use it directly from source?

I tried some of the solutions like in Visual Studio 
File -> Project From Existing Code --

didn't seem to work in my case. I don't want to reorganize the folder structure (like put all "includes", "src" etc) for obvious reasons, but can I ask Visual Studio to look up the files within the folders ?

Comment: You only have source code? No build files whatsoever?

Comment: Yes, I have a ton of folders here :
http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/production-version-600

I can use it in linux pretty well, but I want to use in Visual Studio with other libraries as well.

Comment: You've got a cmake file in there. I'm not super comfortable with using that, but you might want to look into modifying that to generate your visual studio files

Comment: Cool, thanks for pointing that out. I ran "cmake" a got a ROOT.sln file, how can I proceed from there. 

Here's the snapshot : https://app.box.com/s/ejehuhhdg8ck09v2x9eb

Comment: Well you've got a bunch of project files now. I  am hoping that those include the code files in each respective directory. You'll want those projects in your solution (sln) file. Then figure out what dependencies are missing. 

BTW this question is probably too specific for this site and may end up being closed

Comment: @Boumbles I appreciate your suggestions. Thanks, I will try out !